Is the square of any linear multivariable function also convex?
Is the square of any linear multivariable function also convex?
For 2D case I am able to prove:
$$ f(x,y) = (ax + by + c)^{2} =(ax+by)^{2} + 2c(ax+by) + c^{2}  $$
The last two terms already convex when combined, so we care for $g(x,y) = (ax+by)^{2}$, which the Hessian is
$$ H = \begin{bmatrix} 2a^{2} & 2ab \\ 2ab & 2b^{2} \end{bmatrix} $$
then $[x, y] H [x, y]^{T} = 2(ax + by)^{2} \ge 0$,so $g(x,y)$ is convex and therefore $f(x,y)$ is convex. Does it hold for $n$-dimensional linear function?

Let $a$ be a vector and $c$ be a scalar, $$f(x) = (a^Tx+c)^2$$
$$\nabla f(x) = 2a(a^Tx+c)$$
$$\nabla^2 f (x) = 2aa^T$$ which is positive semidefinite, thus the result holds as well.
